# highchart funnel horizontal

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I used highchart and my goal create horizontal funnel chart, in the left side bigger data in the right less data. I did not found in documentation how to use funnel chart with horizontal orientation. I created some trick with area chart and series data zones. And look this is like what I needed, but one problem, I need tooltip for each zones and each zone block must be light, for now only the borders. And whould be good if xAxis contain zones label. Who know trick how to create horizontal funnel with tooltip ? Tooltip must will show `8` or `7` or `14` or `16` or `5` or `4` with some label for each block

my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ouwvdt8r/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you think about create a horizontal funnel by using polygon series? I think that it is much easier to achieve your requirements - in the series object you need to define a name which will be visible in the tooltip and you can easily customize xAxis labels via using xAxis positioner callback.

```
  series: [{
    name: 'value for tooltip',
    type: 'polygon',
    data: [
      [0, 0],
      [0, 10],
      [5, 9],
      [5, 1]
    ],
  }],
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9x0ev8rd/

API:

- polygon - https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.polygon.data
- positioner - https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositioner